# How to evaluate $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\left(e^{ix}\right)}{e^{ix}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, alternative-proof

I'm trying to explicitly evaluate the following integral
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\left(e^{ix}\right)}{e^{ix}} dx
$$

I checked on WolframAlpha that the value of the integral is $2 \pi$. Using this, I attempted the following.

---

I analyze the conjugate of the integral and see that
$$
\overline{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\left(e^{ix}\right)}{e^{ix}} dx} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\overline{\sin\left(e^{ix}\right)}}{\overline{e^{ix}}} dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\left(e^{-ix}\right)}{e^{-ix}} dx \overset{\color{blue}{u = -x}}{=}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\left(e^{iu}\right)}{e^{iu}} du
$$
which confirms to us that the integral is real. From here we can simplify our integral by finding $\Re\left(\frac{\sin\left(e^{ix}\right)}{e^{ix}} \right)$.

To avoid clutter, here I defined $c(t) := \cos(t)$ and $s(t):= \sin(t)$. Keeping this in mind, I get that
\begin{align}
\Re\left(\sin\left(e^{ix}\right)e^{-ix} \right) &= \Re\left(\sin(c + is) (c -is) \right) = \Re\left(\frac{e^{-s}e^{ic}-e^{s}e^{ic}}{2i} (c -is) \right)\\
&=\Re\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-s}\left[\underbrace{\color{blue}{c\{c\}}}_{\cos(\cos(t)} + i\underbrace{\color{blue}{s\{c\}}}_{\sin(\cos(t)}\right]- e^{s}\left[c\{c\} -i s\{c\}\right] \right) (-s -ic) \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(-e^{-s}c\{c\}s + e^{s}c\{c\}s +e^{-s}s\{c\}c +e^s s\{c\}c \right)\\
&=s \cos(c) \left(\frac{e^s -e^{-s}}{2}\right) + c \sin(c) \left(\frac{e^s +e^{-s}}{2}\right)\\
&=\sin(t) \cos(\cos(t))\sinh(\sin(t)) + \cos(t) \sin(\cos(t))\cosh(\sin(t))
\end{align}
And here is where I ran into trouble, because I have no idea how I could integrate that last expression. I tried exploiting symmetry, but the function is even, so I don't think I can do much with it without finding an antiderivative (which sounds very unpleasant).

Does anyone know how I could finish my solution? Or alternatively, does anyone know a simpler way in which I can prove this result? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z=e^{ix}$.  Then the integral becomes

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin(z)}{iz^2}\,dz$$

Can you finish?

Comment: I think the idea here is the same as in Zachary's answer, but I don't know how I can evaluate $f(0)$ for $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$.

Comment: Good question.  Note that $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\sin(z)}z=1$

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see. So if I take
$$
f(z) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\sin(z)}{z}  \quad x \neq 0 \\ 
1 \qquad x = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
then I can use this function in Cauchy's formula since it's holomorphic on all $\mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: Indeed.  The singularity is removable.  And once removed renders the function entire.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Cauchy's integral formula. Your integral can be re-written as
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{ix})\,dx,$$
where $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$. Now substitute $u=e^{ix}$, $du/u=idx$ so that your integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(u)}{u}\,du.$$
Here, $\gamma$ denotes the unit circle centered at the origin in the complex plane. Cauchy told us that this integral is just $2\pi f(0)$, or in your case,
$$2\pi.$$
EDIT:
In fact, if $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disk, we have that
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\,d\theta=2\pi f(0).$$

Comment: This is so much easier, thank you! I just have one question, I would need to verify that $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is holomorphic to apply Cauchy's formula, right?

Comment: I'm also unsure about how we got $f(0) = 1$, wouldn't it be indeterminate since it's $\frac{\sin(0)}{0}$?

Comment: @RobertLee Just the numerator has to be holomorphic on and inside your contour. $\sin(z)$ surely is and we have a pole of order 2. Look at the statement of the formula again. However, I believe there is a mistake in this answer, the final answer should be $2\pi f'(0)$ where $f(z) = sin(z)$.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts, I understand that I only need to check $\sin(z)$ to be holomorphic, but I do think that $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is correct, since $f(z) = \sin(z)$ doesn't account for the extra $e^{ix}$ you get from the $u-$sub.

Comment: @RobertLee You need to look at the statement of the theorem again. By Mark's answer, we have that our integral is equal to the contour integral of $\int \dfrac{\sin(z)}{iz^2} dz$ over the unit circle. Now you apply the result of Cauchy to the integral $\int \dfrac{f(z)}{iz^2} dz = \frac{1}{i}2\pi if'(0) = 2\pi \cos(0) = 2\pi$ where $f(z) = \sin(z)$. The reason why we are taking the first derivative follows from the $z^2$ in the denominator. Note, I am using the form of the theorem $f^{(n)}(a) =\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}$

Comment: @NicholasRoberts, ahhh, I get you know.  I was only thinking about the case of $\frac{1}{z^1}$ in the denominator, and not the general $\frac{1}{(z-1)^n}$. But I think I understand now, thank you!

Comment: Ok, no problem. I did not mean to come off as rude or blunt. Looking at your discussion with Mark, I see that you can apply the $\frac{1}{z}$ version of the theorem. But with the more general version of the theorem, the analytic extension of $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is not necessary.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I believe that $f(z)=\sin(z)/z$ (with $f(0)=0$) is holomorphic as it is analytic, and so we can indeed apply the version of the theorem with a pole of order $1$, without a derivative. However, you can also apply Cauchy's Integral formula pretending that you have a pole of order $2$, and obtain a derivative like you did. In both cases, the answer is the same.

Comment: @Zachary Yes, exactly. I see that clearly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the contour integral of $\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}$ over the circle $\gamma$. Parametrizing the circle over the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ gives us $i \int \frac{\sin{e^{ix}}}{e^{iz}} dx$.

We can take the Taylor expansion of $\sin(z)$ to get that the contour integral is equal to $\int_\gamma \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{z^{2i - 1}}{(2i + 1)!} dz$. Since the sum is uniformly convergent over the circle, we can swap the sum and the integral to get $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \int_\gamma \frac{z^{2i -1}}{(2i - 1)!}$. But for $i > 0$, this is the integral of a monomial over a closed path, so the only term that matters is the $i = 0$ term.

Thus, the integral equals $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z} dz = 2 \pi i$.

Then your original integral is, in fact, $2 \pi$.